# SQL Public role audit findings

Tags: sql-server

Our SQL auditors have issues with the Public role being able to query master.sys.syslogins, master.sys.databases, master.sys.configurations from a specific database.  Has anyone had to remove these rights to the Public role and does this cause any issues?  Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately a common false positive when using DB vulnerability scanning tools, and unfortunately there are no absolute answers. It will depend on your particular scenario & auditors to determine if such findings are indeed something you need to change, or accept it as operational risks.

For the most part, I have been able to argue that these permissions are acceptable, especially since the typical best-practice recommendation is to not modify the default permissions granted to public role.

The default permissions granted to public on SQL Server are intended to make tools & some features in SQL Server work, and typically there will be mitigating factors around these permissions.

In the particular case of catalog view access, it is not only governed by having select permission to the catalog view itself, but also by metadata visibility rules. For details Please visit Metadata Visibility Configuration (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187113.aspx) on BOL; I especially recommend reading the "Benefits and Limits of Metadata Visibility Configuration" section.

For example, a low-privileged user in the system will have different visibility on `sys.server_principals` (`master.sys.syslogins` is deprecated) that a user with sysadmin access:

```
CREATE LOGIN [test00] WITH PASSWORD = '<s3cr3t P@zzw0Rd>';
ALTER LOGIN [test00] DISABLE;
CREATE LOGIN [test01] WITH PASSWORD = '<s3cr3t P@zzw0Rd>';
ALTER LOGIN [test01] DISABLE;
CREATE SERVER ROLE [srvrole00]; 
go

ALTER SERVER ROLE [srvrole00] ADD MEMBER [test00]
go

SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals  -- Can see all server principals
EXECUTE ('SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals') AS LOGIN = 'test00' -- besides the system principals, can see only himself & the server role he is a member of
EXECUTE ('SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals') AS LOGIN = 'test01'  -- besides the system principals, can see only himself 
go
```

You will notice on the results that the 3 principals have a different view of the metadata.

If your SQL auditors think any of these permissions is not acceptable for any reason, you may revoke the permission as they deems as necessary, but the cave-at is that such actions are likely to limit (or in some cases completely break) functionality of SQL server and/or tools. I would strongly recommend looking at what operations they are trying to block/prevent, and act accordingly.

For example. For access to DB metadata, there is one special permission granted by default to public: `VIEW ANY DATABASE`. This permission was introduced to allow users using SSMS & similar tools to navigate to different databases.

Revoking this permission will affect how some tools work in order to allow you to switch between databases, but it doesn't change the access to the DB; therefore it may be an acceptable trade-off if your users do not need such functionality and you want to prevent users from looking at all the DB metadata.

I hope this information helps. Please feel free to follow up with any question. I will be glad to help.

-Raul

Answer (score 0):

None of our general users even have public access to the Master database, and likely shouldn't in most environments.  Only DBAs really need access to the Master database generally.  As long as you only grant the public role on the Master database to logins that have any business being in it... then it's really not necessary to remove the public role from any objects in there.  If you remove the public role access to those objects, then only system administrators will be able to query them.